# Why is only 1==TRUE, true, in R and other numbers are false?

Tags: r, logical-operators

What happens if an if() statement doesn’t contain a logical expression?

For example, the if-else block if(2){print("A")}else{print("B")}) outputs A, but 2 is not true so it should print B. Why?

Answer (score 4):

It is because any value other than 0 would be coerced to TRUE while 0 will be FALSE in the `if`

```
if(2){print("A")}else{print("B")}
#[1] "A"
if(1) print("A")
#[1] "A"

if(0) print("A") else print("B")
#[1] "B"
```

---

It can be checked with `as.logical`

```
as.logical(c(0, 1, 2, -1, 5, 3))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Here the TRUE will be mapped to 1 and FALSE to 0 (binary) and `if` can have only two cases either TRUE or FALSE.

---

There was another question in the title and that was why `1== TRUE`.  The reason is that TRUE/FALSE is internally 1/0. So, 1 gets coerced to TRUE or TRUE to 1 during the `==` while other numbers remains as such

Comment: @user2554330 the code in the OP's post shows the OP is passing only a number

Comment: @user2554330. that is easy to explain as TRUE/FALSE is coerced to 1/0 (internal representation) and that is the reason 1 == TRUE

Answer (score 1):

You ask two separate questions.

First, the one in your title asks why 1 is the only number that tests equal to `TRUE`.  The comparison `x == TRUE` needs both `x` and `TRUE` to be the same type. Usually logicals like `TRUE` will be converted to the same type as `x`.  (The only exception is if `x` is type "raw", which is rarely used.  It would be converted to logical.)

If `x` is a number, then it stays as is, and `TRUE` is converted to the number 1.  So the comparison becomes `x == 1`, and that's only true when `x` is 1.  If `x` had been a character value, `TRUE` would become `"TRUE"`, and that's the only equal value.

Your second question is about what happens when a non-logical `condition` is used in `if(condition)`.  In that case, `condition` is converted to a logical value.  For numbers there are three possibilities:  0 becomes `FALSE`, `NA` or `NaN` gives an error, and any other number becomes `TRUE`.  For characters, a few different values (`"FALSE"`, `"F"`, `"false"` and `"False"`) give `FALSE`, and a few give `TRUE`, but most give an error.